# ansible: Error creating 16 partitions using parted module

Tags: ansible, parted

I'm trying to create 16 partitions from a 4TB block device with ansible.  I'm using the parted module: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/parted_module.html#examples

I verified the device is connected and the kernel sees it, according to dmesg:

```sh
[root@ZUSE1DLMSORDB1 YoCp19h2cn]# dmesg | grep sdd
[    5.837562] sd 5:0:0:11: [sdd] 8589934592 512-byte logical blocks: (4.39 TB/4.00 TiB)
[    5.837564] sd 5:0:0:11: [sdd] 4096-byte physical blocks
[    5.858252] sd 5:0:0:11: [sdd] Write Protect is off
[    5.858254] sd 5:0:0:11: [sdd] Mode Sense: 0f 00 10 00
[    5.858449] sd 5:0:0:11: [sdd] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, supports DPO and FUA
[    5.911159]  sdd: sdd1
[    5.930018] sd 5:0:0:11: [sdd] Attached SCSI disk
```

According to what I have read, if I need to create a lot of partitions I need to create an extended partition (?) with GPT partition table.  The reason for the GPT partition table is the extended partition will be large than 2TiB.  After creating the extended partition I can then create 16 logical partitions.  (I think my assumptions are correct.)

Here is the playbook I created to, but unfortunately I'm getting errors running it.

```
---
- name: Create a new extended (to hold all the logical partitions) partition
  parted:
    device: /dev/sdd
    number: 1
    part_type: extended
    label: gpt
    name: UberPartition
    state: present

- name: Create 16 (= 4096 / 256) logical partitions
  parted:
    device: /dev/sdd1
    number: "{{ item }}"
    part_type: logical
    part_end: 16%
    unit: GB
    state: present
  with_sequence: count=16
```

When I run it I get the following errors (I'm running the playbook via AWX):

```
{
    "_ansible_parsed": true,
    "changed": false,
    "_ansible_item_label": "2",
    "err": "/sbin/parted: invalid token: logical\nError: Expecting a partition type.\n",
    "_ansible_no_log": false,
    "_ansible_item_result": true,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "part_start": "0%",
            "part_end": "16%",
            "name": "disk_2",
            "align": "optimal",
            "number": 2,
            "label": "msdos",
            "state": "present",
            "part_type": "logical",
            "flags": null,
            "device": "/dev/sdd",
            "unit": "GB"
        }
    },
    "item": "2",
    "rc": 1,
    "msg": "Error while running parted script: /sbin/parted -s -m -a optimal /dev/sdd -- unit GB mkpart logical 0% 16%",
    "_ansible_ignore_errors": null,
    "out": ""
}
```

I can't figure out what is wrong.  I tried a myriad different things and nothing seem to be working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi according to documentation https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/parted_module.html the part_type should be only specified with the "'msdos' or 'dvh' partition tables."

Comment: GPT also supports up to 128 partitions. Why are you making some "uberpartition", then logical partitions?

Comment: This is where my lack of disk partition knowledge is causing me to do dumb things.   So are saying I can create 16 GPT partitions?

Comment: If disk is GPT - yes :).

Comment: You might have to dumb this down for me.  What makes a disk GPT? Isn't that something I do with parted/fdisk? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this using percentage, with 16 equal partitions, I used the same playbook as described by @Gerb.

`

```
    - name: Create 16 equal partition  
      parted:
        device: /dev/sdd
        number: "{{ (item | int | abs) + 1 }}"
        label: linx
        flags: [ lvm ]
        name: "disk{{ (item | int | abs) + 1 }}"
        part_start: "{{ (item | int | abs) * 6.25 }}%"
        part_end: "{{ (item | int | abs) * 6.25 + 6.25 }}%"
        unit: "%"
        state: present
      with_sequence: start=0 count=16
```

`

Note that 100/16 = 6.25

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create 16 partitions using this playbook:

```
---
- name: Create 16 (= 4096 / 256) partitions
  parted:
    device: /dev/sdd
    number: "{{ (item | int | abs) + 1 }}"
    label: gpt
    name: "disk_{{ (item | int | abs) + 1 }}"
    part_start: "{{ (item | int | abs) * 256 }}GB"
    part_end: "{{ (item | int | abs) * 256 + 256 }}GB"
    unit: GB
    state: present
  with_sequence: start=0 count=16
```